# Central Authentication Service (CAS) Reauthentication for Secure Content

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

I'm designing an SSO solution for my company using CAS. One requirement I'm facing that I'm not sure how to deal with is that one of the apps being fronted by CAS has a few pages considered "Highly Sensitive". While all apps should use CAS, when a user wants to access these particular pages, depending on business rules, they may be required to log in again.

I've seen something similar done in spring security using the "Remember Me" functionality to represent the broader idea of being logged in, but I would expect things to be different with CAS. For instance, assuming I've detected that reauthentication is required, forwarding a user back to the CAS login would simply allow the user to auto-login again. Or am I asking too much of CAS in this case and should I just write my own secondary login?